# VBA WorksheetFunction.Countif not counting variable in column

Tags: excel, vba, countif

1. Goal is to count number of times a variable's value appears in the named range (of a table).
2. Expected result is that the below code will return a count of X for July 1, when in fact it gives 0.
3. See below code (Have removed other code which is just noise in this context)

   ```
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim row As Variant
    Dim date_count As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table2")
    row=2

    date1=tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Item(row).Value 'date1 successfully recognised by VBA as #1/07/2020# (date type: Date)
    date_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("dates"), "=" & date1)
   ```

Despite 01/07/2020 appearing in the named range >20 times, the date count is returned by VBA as 0 (date type: integer). Am I doing something wrong in the date_count line??

Thanks team

Comment: Keep in mind a Date without a Time value means "exactly at midnight" - so if you compare 2 date values, and one of them has a time value (that is not midnight) also (even tho you may have formatted it to only show the date part) then it will not match.

Comment: Are you sure `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("dates")` refers to what you think it does?  Maye that should be `tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange`

Comment: Could you share what *named range (of a table)* refers to? That's quite unexpected. For example, if it is a column header, you could do something like `.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Table2[dates]"), date1)`. Also, keep in mind that `row = 2` is used as the second row of the `DataBodyRange` which is the third row of the table.

Comment: Thankyou dear strangers of the interwebs, resolved as per edit above.
Cheers from Brisbane Australia

Comment: Please don't edit an answer into the question.  Add it as an _Answer_ instead.  Answering your own question is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed date_count line as below.

```
date_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange, date1)
```